# How do I make a split input that is regex friendly?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, search, standards, textbox

I have a web application that requires the user to enter text that is used to split another string. While I want it to be regex-friendly, I don't want it to confuse new users. For example, if the user wants to split by the period (.) character, it wouldn't work if the app is using regex because it would match anything. On the other hand, the user might want to split by a complex pattern and understands regex. I can add a note that regex is supported, but it wouldn't solve the problem because most people don't know what regex is.

My initial thought was to use a "prefix" to enable regex. For example, "re" would have to be the at the beginning for regex to be enabled, and the rest of the text could be a regex pattern. The benefit of this is that new users would not find "bugs" that were just regex working but advanced users can easily use regex.

What is the recommended way to do this? In other words, is there any standard for this?

Comment: What if the user wants to split with "re" (or "read", or "real", or "ready" etc)?

Comment: That's what I was thinking could be a problem. Maybe it could be "r*" instead of "re" because normal users wouldn't want to split with something with a star in it usually.

Answer (score 1):

I often see a checkbox next to the input field which enables regex. All the text in the input field will then be interpreted as a regular expression.

The problem I see with your approach is that it would not really be discoverable that you can use regex by prefixing your input with "re". Also, what would happen if you would want to split a word which contains "re" in the middle? That would make things messy.

[image: Search & replace with regex]

Comment: I understand, but approach is to just match the beginning with "re" and put a note of it somewhere else so it is easily discoverable.